# Foreign keys used as data to negate join operations for optimization statergy

Tags: sql, django

If I have a table for location data:

table Locations

PK:Location_ID ,Country, State, City

```
  1           RSA     EC     GRH
  2           USA     NY     NY city
  3           RSA     WC     Cape Town
```

table User Profiles

PK:User  ,name , surname, FK: Location_ID

```
  1    John,   Cp          1
  2    Luck,   dv          3
  3    pete,   hrt         2
```

My confusion, if foreign keys are only for referential integrity does this mean that: Table User Profile : Column Location_ID does not hold data....

I would like to avoid joins for performance reasons. hence could I say:

The User supplies country, state and city on sign up:so look up Location_ID in Locations table. insert into User Profiles table the Location_ID found in Locations Table into User Profile Table: Location_ID.

Then on finding all users with the same location I would just need to query the Profile tables Location_ID to find those users... So should I then make the Table User Profiles : Location_ID a column which is not a foreign key instead..

The scenario is match the users in a country with the same set of interests,

which lives in another table called Interest

PK: User , Interest

```
 1      golf
 2      cricket
 3      swimming
 1      Rugby
 2      golf
```

Thus using code , I would say the users from location_Id:1 in user profile table, use the user to query interest in interest table. hence returning user and interest for further process with code.

A text book I am using seems to use the foreign key as data for location as set up above

PK = primary key and FK = foreign key.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: FK are for referential integrity, but data is still stored in the Location ID column.  Also, using a join with 1 call to the database is better than using multiple calls to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great explanation of foreign keys in the Django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

An explanation of using foreign keys in Model relationships here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#relationships

A foreign is exactly what you want. By default, no join should be performed, and the foreign key will return as an integer.

**MODELS**

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField()
    state = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    surname = models.CharField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='users')


class Interest(models.Model):
    interest = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='interests')
```

**Multiple Queries**

```
# This is NOT the best way to do it
# but I think it is what you are asking for as it contains no JOIN
# Multiple database hits are almost always more intensive than 
# a single request with a few joins

 # choose location id
location_id = 1

# get a list of user ids for the location
user_ids = User.objects.filter(location=location_id) \
    .values_list('id', flat=True)

# get interests from the list of user ids
location_user_interests = Interest.objects \
    .filter(user__in=user_ids) \
    .values_list('interest', flat=True)
print(location_user_interests

# OUTPUT: ['golf', 'rugby']
# QUERY TIME: 2.970 ms
```

**One Query**

```
# choose location id
location_id = 1

# I think you will find this to be cleaner and faster
location_user_interests = Location.objects \
    .filter(id=location_id) \
    .prefetch_related('users', 'users__interests') \
    .values_list('users__interests__interest', flat=True)
print(location_user_interests)

# OUTPUT: ['golf', 'rugby']
# QUERY TIME: 0.660 ms
```

Comment: thank you that was very helpful...I am struggling to understand : .values_list('users__interests__interest', flat=True)... how is this constructed... also how do i get the users name attached , assuming i want it returned as an array of an array

Comment: You are welcome. An explanation of the values_list function is available in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list. For a more fundamental understanding of the QuerySet API, you should read the entire page, not just the section. Since your initial question was concluded, please help me out by accepting the answer.